# Localizar ficheiros contendo string e renomear

Tags: linux, arquivo, algoritmo-de-busca, bash

Para localizar ficheiros cujo nome contém determinada *string*, podemos recorrer ao [`find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) da seguinte forma:

Exemplo do ficheiro:

> 1429331804.H568641P9577.xxxx.example.com,S=17846:2,

Comando para localizar por `xxxx.example.com`:

```
find . -type f -name "*xxxx.example.com*"
```

E isto vai devolver apenas os ficheiros que contém a *string* indicada.

## Pergunta

Como renomear os ficheiros devolvidos substituindo a porção chave para outro valor?

> 1429331804.H568641P9577.**xxxx.example.com**,S=17846:2,

Passa para:

> 1429331804.H568641P9577.**yyyy.superbubu.pt**,S=17846:2,

Comment: Se você estiver escrevendo um script bash você pode colocar o nome dos arquivos em uma variável e depois usar `sed` para alterar o nome dos arquivos usando expressões regulares. E depois vc usa `mv fich_orig fich_dest`.

Comment: É possível usar o `find` com a opção `exec`, que roda um comando com cada resultado retornado pelo `find`. Veja http://rberaldo.com.br/find-como-encontrar-arquivos-linux/

Answer (score 4):

Se você tem ou pode instalar o programa `rename` e se todos os ficheiros estão no mesmo diretório:

```
rename 's/xxxx.example.com/yyyy.superbubu.pt/' *
```

Comment: Cool +1 (o rename faz mesmo parte do meu kit de sobrevivênca :)

Answer (score 1):

A solução do @Clayton Stanley pode ser composta com o `find` do OP para situações
em que os ficheiros estejam em subdiretórios:

```
find -type f -name "*xxxx.example.com*" \
             -exec rename 's/xxxx.example.com/yyyy.superbubu.pt/' {} \;
```

(às vezes o fantástico comando rename (escrito pelo Larry Wall!) está disponível com
o nome prename)

Answer (score 0):

Aqui vai uma possível solução usando bash script.

**script.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Cria um arquivo texto com a lista de todos os resultados do find
# Cada linha eh um arquivo encontrado
find . -type f -name "*xxxx.example.com*" > lista.txt

# For-loop dentro do arquivo
while read p; do
    # O nome do arquivo origem eh a linha p
    ORIG=$p
    echo $ORIG

    # O nome do arquivo destino eh a linha p substituindo a URL
    DEST="$(echo $ORIG | sed s/xxxx.example.com/yyyy.superbubu.pt/)"
    echo $DEST

    # Copia o arquivo ORIG para DEST
    cp $ORIG $DEST
    # Altere cp para mv se voce tiver certeza que funciona
done <lista.txt

# Remove o arquivo lista.txt
rm lista.txt
```